# foreach loop in expect script not accepting variables

Tags: foreach, tcl, expect

```
#!/bin/bash
expect << EOF
exp_internal 1

spawn ssh nbhambha@10.118.137.78
expect "ssword:"
send "********\r"
sleep 3
set list [open list1 r]

foreach line \$list 
{
   expect " $"
   send "seeisso \$list | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'"
   send "\r"
   sleep 5
   expect -re " $"
   set fid [open out1.txt a]
   puts \$fid \$expect_out(buffer)
}
close $fid

EOF
```

======

List 1 contains:

APSE0112

ETLLT0000

=============

result of the script:

```
expect: does " " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern " $"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) " "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " "
send: sending "seeisso file7 | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'" to { exp6 }
send: sending "\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression " $"? no


expect: does "\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression " $"? no
seeisso file7 | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'

expect: does "\r\nseeisso file7 | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression " $"? no
```

===================

I don't know from where it is taking file7 value.
and when i change:

`send "seeisso \$list | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'"`

to

`send "seeisso **$list** | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'"`

it takes an empty value:

```
expect: set expect_out(0,string) " "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " "

send: sending "seeisso  | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'" to { exp6 }
send: sending "\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression " $"? no


expect: does "\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression " $"? no
seeisso  | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'
```

===========

Please help

Comment: Why do you have a backslash before `$list`, (i.e. `\$list`)? Also, I don't see your use of the `line` variable.

Comment: In a bash here-doc, if you single-quote the here-doc terminator, you effectively single-quote the whole thing. That would alleviate much of your escaping. However, the entire bash script is effectively an expect program. Do away with bash altogether. Change the she-bang line to: `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`.

Comment: A Tcl error: commands are terminated by semicolons and newlines, so you *must* place the opening brace on the *same* line as the foreach command.

Answer (score 2):

I saw a couple of problems:

1. `list` in your case is really a file handle, not the contents of the file.
2. You have backslash before `$list`, which I don't understand the reason
3. You don't use your `line` variable

Here is a suggestion to see if it works:

```
set fileHandle [open list1]
while {[gets $fileHandle line] != -1} {
    expect " $"
    send "seeisso $line | grep -E -i ' os |proddropdown|hostname'"
    send "\r"
    # the rest ...
}
close $fileHandle
```

Comment: I tried your code and got following error:send: sending "password\r" to { exp6 }
can not find channel named "line"
    while executing
"gets  line"

Comment: I tried your code using expect(not in bash) and it worked thanks.
Not sure why it was not working with bash script.